# MongoDB request with the condition do not display

Tags: php, mongodb

```
"bookName": "I've been discovered",
    "bookGenre": {
         "0": "Classics",
         "1": "Fantasy",
         "2": "Romance"
    }

"bookName": "Doctor Who",
"bookGenre": {
     "0": "Classics",
     "1": "Biography"
}

"bookName": "I don't want to tread carefully",
"bookGenre": {
     "0": "Classics",
     "1": "Fantasy",
     "2": "History"
}
```

I want to get all the books in the genre Classics, but excluding the genre Fantasy and History.

```
$genre = array("Classics");
$genreNot = array("Fantasy", "History");

$q = find(array("bookGenre" => array('$in' => $genre), "bookGenre" => array('$nin' => $genreNot)));
```

In this query, I get all my books, and the exception is not bringing the genre Fantasy and History does not work.
How to make a request to the excluded genre work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm you have got a fundamental problem with your arrays here:

```
$q = find(array("bookGenre" => array('$in' => $genre), 
"bookGenre" => array('$nin' => $genreNot)));
```

You have duplicate keys for the same object so actually the only clause in this query that goes through is `"bookGenre" => array('$nin' => $genreNot)`. I believe instead you can combine the `$in` and `$nin`:

```
$q = find(array(
             "bookGenre" => array('$in' => $genre, '$nin' => $genreNot)
));
```

Like so.

Comment: OMG, an elementary check request. Thank you, I'll be careful.